# indexOf return -1

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, array-bidimensional

soy principiante en google-app-scrip.
Estoy tratando de resolver un problema. Les comento, necesito poder encontrar la posición de un dato, dentro de un vector. Para esto realicé la siguiente funcion.

```
function myFunctionIndexOF() {

var EquiposStock = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EquiposStock");

var datosOriginales= EquiposStock.getRange(2, 1,EquiposStock.getLastRow(),1).getValues()[0];

//var filtro = '23?57';


var pos = datosOriginales[0].indexOf('23?57');


Logger.log('POSICION',pos);
Logger.log(datosOriginales);




}
```

Pero me está retornando -1 en.... Por favor, alguien podrá ayudarme a resolver este inconveniente.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

El problemas es que estás aplicando `indexOf` a un string en lugar de hacerlo a un Array

Te doy mas detalles

getValues() devuelve un array bidimiensional pero sólo estás asignando una fila a datos originales porque has puesto `[0]`;

```
var datosOriginales= EquiposStock.getRange(2, 1,EquiposStock.getLastRow(),1).getValues()[0];
```

luego `datosOriginales[0]` devuelve un `string`, es por ello que

```
datosOriginales[0].indexOf('23?57')
```

le asigna `-1` a `pos`

Si deseas buscar en la primera fila de los datos tomados del rango devuelto por `EquiposStock.getRange(2, 1,EquiposStock.getLastRow(),1)` quita el `[0]` de uno de los dos lugares donde lo has incluido.

Comment: @AdolfoEnriqueLobos Te sugiero publicar una nueva pregunta en la que indiques claramente lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: hola @ Ruben, es verdad el [0] del getValues está de más. lo quité. pero sigo con el problema. lo que trato de hacer es buscar la fila en la que se encuentra el valor '23?57' . Tu me puedes guiar para poder resolverlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Con mucho gusto te guío. Empieza por seguir mi sugerencia en el comentario previo: Publica una nueva pregunta en la que indiques claramente lo que deseas hacer. Aprovecho además para sugerirte que incluyas en la pregunta misma datos de ejemplo así  como un enlace a una hoja de cálculo de demostración compartida con cualquiera que tenga el enlace para ver.