# Cómo encontrar la posición de un determinado elemento dentro de un vector

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, array-bidimensional

Esta es una pregunta de seguimiento de [indexOf return -1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/361965/).

Realicé una función que busca la posición de un determinado elemento dentro de un vector.  Para esto utilicé `indexOf` pero devuelve `-1` aunque veo que el elemento buscado se encuentra en la posición `55` del vector.

Comparto la función y el resultado para que me puedan ayudar.

```
function myFunctionIndexOF() {

  var EquiposStock = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                   .getSheetByName("EquiposStock");
  var datosOriginales = EquiposStock.getRange(2, 1, EquiposStock.getLastRow(), 1)
                                    .getValues(); 

  var filtro = '23?57';

  var pos = datosOriginales.indexOf('23?57');

  Logger.log('ÀCA SE ENCUENTRA', datosOriginales[55]);
  Logger.log('POSICION',pos);
  Logger.log(datosOriginales);

}
```

Resultado

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas pasando por alto que `getValues()` devuelve una matriz (también lo podemos llamar vector de vectores, Array bidimensional entre otras formas)

De hecho, el registro te da pistas de ello cuando `Logger.log('ÀCA SE ENCUENTRA', datosOriginales[55]);` escribe `[23?57]` (los corchetes indican que se trata de un vector, y como no hay comas, que este contiene un elemento)

En términos de hoja de cálculo, en lugar de "vector" como el que se muestra como resultado de `Logger.log(datosOriginales);` se usa **columna** y a la posición nos referimos como **fila**, entonces, podemos decir que lo que estas buscando es encontrar la fila en la que se encuentra `23?57` en la **Columna A**.

Una forma simple es usar un bucle y para ello el que se encuentra más comunmente es `for`

```
function myFunctionIndexOF() {

  var EquiposStock = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                   .getSheetByName("EquiposStock");
  var datosOriginales = EquiposStock.getRange(2, 1, EquiposStock.getLastRow(), 1)
                                    .getValues(); 

  var filtro = '23?57';

  // var pos = datosOriginales.indexOf('23?57');

  var filas = datosOriginales.length;

  for(var fila = 0; fila < filas; fila++){

    if( datosOriginales[fila][0] === '23?57') break;

  }



  Logger.log('ÀCA SE ENCUENTRA', datosOriginales[55]);
 // Logger.log('POSICION',pos);
  Logger.log('POSICION', fila);
  Logger.log(datosOriginales);

}
```

Toma en cuenta que los índices de los Array en Google Apps Script/JavaScript son base 0 y que la numeración de filas de la hoja de cálculo de Google es base 1. Dependiendo del uso que la vayas a dar a la "posición" habría que ajustar el número de fila considerando que los datos han sido tomados a partir de la fila 2.

Puedes usar otros bucles e incluso métodos de `Array`